# Rellenar vector dinámico con datos

Tags: c++, vectores

`x` tiene que ser introducido por el usuario intente algo pero esta super mal.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define L 100

int A[L];
void asignacion(int &);
void imprime(int &);

int main() {
  int n;
  printf("Introduce la longitud del arreglo");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  asignacion(n);
  imprime(n);
  getch();
}

void asignacion(int &x) {
  int dato, i;
  for (x = 0; x < i;)

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      dato = ();
      A[i] = dato;
    }
}

void imprime(int &x) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    printf(" %d", A[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Porfavor revisa que la funcion `asignacion` la hayas copiado correctamente, ya de que la forma en la que esta escrita no tiene ningun sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Pides datos para después sobrescribirlos:

```
int n;
printf("Introduce la longitud del arreglo");
scanf("%d", &n);
asignacion(n);
```

El valor que almacenas en `n` y después lo pasas por referencia a la función `asignacion` para escribirlo con cero (`0`), ignorando lo que fuera que tuviera antes:

```
void asignacion(int &x) {
  int dato, i;
  for (x = 0; x < i;)
//     ^ <--- Pones '0' en la variable, sobrescribiendo el valor anterior.
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      dato = ();
      A[i] = dato;
    }
}
```

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
void asignacion(int &x) {
  for (int indice = 0; indice < x; ++indice)
//     ^ <--- Declaración de variable
      std::cin >> A[indice];
//             ^ <--- Leer datos
  }
}
```